# Java Postfix Increment Operator Behavior

Tags: java, operators

In the sample code below, why is the end value different after each method.  I would expect both to display "i = 1"

```
public class Test {

    public int i = 0;    

    public static void main( String args[] ) {        
        Test t = new Test();
        t.test();
    }

    public void test() {

        i = 0;
        System.out.println( "[start a] i = " + i );
        doSomethingA( i++ );
        System.out.println( "[end   a] i = " + i );

        System.out.println( "---------------------" );

        i = 0;
        System.out.println( "[start b] i = " + i );
        doSomethingB( i++ );
        System.out.println( "[end   b] i = " + i );

    }

    // Direct assignment of passed value
    public void doSomethingA( int x ) {
        i = x;
    }

    // Equation of passed value
    public void doSomethingB( int x ) {
        i += x;
    }

}
```

The results are:

```
[start a] i = 0
[end   a] i = 0
---------------------
[start b] i = 0
[end   b] i = 1
```

Why does it matter what I do to 'i' in the methods, shouldn't it increment by 1 after the method ends?

In both cases I am assigning the value of 'i' to 0 inside the method.

Thanks

Comment: http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what happens when calling both methods from `test`.

First.

`i` starts out at `0` and `0` is printed.  `i++` is evaluated.  Because it's post-increment, the expression value is the old value, `0`, so that is what's passed to `doSomethingA`.  The post-increment leaves `i` at `1`.  `doSomethingA` assigns `x` (`0`) back to `i`, so `0` is printed.

Second.

`i` starts out at `0` and `0` is printed.  `i++` is evaluated.  Because it's post-increment, the expression value is the old value, `0`, so that is what's passed to `doSomethingB`.  The post-increment leaves `i` at `1`.  `doSomethingB` adds `x` (`0`) to `i`, so `i` remains `1`, and `1` is printed.

Comment: My clearly wrong thought in this matter was that i would be incremented after the method.   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
System.out.println("i=" + i + ", x=" + x);
```

at start of `doSomethingA` and `doSomethingB` methods and you will see that in both cases

```
i=1, x=0
```

This is because in

```
method(i++);
```

first current value of `i` is passed to method making `x = 0`, then field `i` is incremented (to `1`) and then body of method is executed. So when inside methods body you do

```
i = x;
```

you are setting `i` to `0`

but if you do

```
i += x;
```

you are adding `0` to current value of `i` which is `1` which doesn't change value of `i`.